# Query stopped working

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

The following code stopped working, not entering the while loop at all although there exist 'staff' posts. How can I start trying to find out what's going on? Only think that's changed I think is I updated to wordpress 4...  I have updated permalinks. Thanks

```
    <?php
$args      = array(
    'post_type' => 'staff',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'Staff order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$staffLoop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($staffLoop->have_posts()):
    $staffLoop->the_post();
    $id = str_replace(' ', '', get_the_title());
    echo '<a href="#' . $id . '" class="portrait"> 
                                        <div class="facebox"><span class="face-name">';
    $firstName = explode(' ', trim(get_the_title()));
    echo $firstName[0];
    echo '</span>';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</div></a>';
endwhile;
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: WordPress debugging 101, this will save you a lot of hassle in the future. Make sure you're on a development/local environment so you're not messing with a live site.  If you need help migrating WordPress, see [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) guide. Deactivate all plugins and switch to a default theme. Make sure whatever problem you were having is solved. Then, reactivate the plugins and theme one by one to figure out which one is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the problem is related to Polylang. Everything is fine when it's inactive and even when it's active but with the option "activate languages for custom posts (staff)" unselected. The problem appears when I select to translate this custom post...